# Can you give me a tip about the function fit my plot?

Tags: exponential-function, curves

I am trying to find a function fit to my data [plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2L5d.jpg). And these are the $x-y$ data:

$x$: 0.0020    0.0050    0.0100    0.0200    0.0500    0.1000    0.2000    0.5000    1.0000

$y$: 4.4417    4.5548    4.8820    5.4256   21.5676   46.8372   50.1357   67.5797  623.3367

It will be much appreciated if you may tip me what kind of function behavior can be close. My guess was $tanh$ which has the slope of zero at $x=0$ but I was not quite successful.

$y$ are the critical load to rupture an elastomer vulcanize by solid particle and the $x$ are normalized sizes of particles.

Comment: strong law of small numbers came to mind but, the formula may depend on how each component of the data is derived.

Comment: That is true because for big particles ($x$ is small) the elastomer rupture easily i.e. requires a small load to rupture. I have no clue what the base function of calculation is because they are derived from Finite Element. However, I know the material behaves exponentially and the exponential function survives during the calculations.

Comment: I don't know a good formula, but [here is graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ajartxqre). It is plotted log log, but you can easily modify it. Here is another [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fjfutzodar). X axis is in decibels (10 decibels equals a factor of 10,  4 decibels a factor of 2.5, and 3 decibels a factor of 2). Y axis is $\sqrt{}$